# Turn dplyr group_by/summarize/spread into a function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, rlang

I have the following data (some organizations, kpi measurements, long list of variables (i gave two in the example).

```
   df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ORG_NM, ~KPI_NM,        ~NUMR_VAL,       ~DENO_VAL,
    "AAA",   "xxx",                8,              10,
    "AAA",   "xxx",               10,              10,
    "BBB",   "xxx",                1,               7,
    "CCC",   "xxx",                9,               3,
    "CCC",   "yyy",                9,               4,
    "DDD",   "xxx",                1,               7,
    "AAA",   "yyy",                8,               3,
    "BBB",   "yyy",                6,               1
  )
```

I would like to summarize each of the variables and generate a wide table so that each organization has only one record. So far my approach was to use repetitive code in which I need to change,
- summarise part with a name of a variable to be summarized and a function this variable should be processed with,
- spread part - value = change the name of the new column,
- rename_at - add meaningful suffix to all spread columns with values, showing what function was used to achieve them.
At the end I need to change the name of the dataframe in full_join to append the new columns.

```
library(tidyverse)    


df_numrtr <- df %>%    
  group_by(ORG_NM, KPI_NM) %>%    
  summarise(mean_NUM_VAL = mean(NUMR_VAL)) %>%    
  spread(key = c(KPI_NM),  mean_NUM_VAL) %>%      
  ungroup() %>%    
  rename_at(vars(-ORG_NM), function(x) paste0(x, "_num_mean"))


df_denom  <- df %>%   
  group_by(ORG_NM, KPI_NM) %>%    
  summarise(mean_DENOM_VAL = mean(DENO_VAL)) %>%    
  spread(key = c(KPI_NM),  mean_DENOM_VAL) %>%      
  ungroup() %>%    
  rename_at(vars(-ORG_NM), function(x)    
    paste0(x, "_den_mean"))



df_final <-    
  df_numrtr %>%     
  full_join(df_denom) %>%     
  select(ORG_NM, sort(names(.))) 

  ORG_NM xxx_den_mean xxx_num_mean yyy_den_mean yyy_num_mean
  <chr>         <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1 AAA              10            9            3            8
2 BBB               7            1            1            6
3 CCC               3            9            4            9
4 DDD               7            1           NA           NA
```

i would like to get rid of repetitive code and have a function that will take in a name of a variable and a function. My desired function in pseudocode would look like

```
fnSummarize <- function(df, my_org_var, my_kpi_var, my_var, my_fun ){
  df_output<-df %>%    
    group_by({{my_groupby_var}}) %>%    
    summarise(paste0({{my_var}},"_",{{my_fun}}) = my_fun({{my_var}})) %>%    
    spread(key = {{my_kpi_var}},  paste0(my_var, my_fun)) %>%      
    ungroup()  %>% 
    rename_at(vars(-{{ my_org_var}}), function(x) paste0(x, {{myfun}}))
  return(df_output)
}
```

How to properly inject column names and a function to be used in the process (like mean, sum, median, sd) to such a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are quite close. The problem is composition of the column name, which I pulled out into a separate line:

```
fnSummarize <- function(df, my_org_var, my_kpi_var, my_var, my_fun ){
  colName <- str_c( rlang::enexpr(my_var),"_",rlang::enexpr(my_fun) )

  df %>%
    group_by( {{my_org_var}}, {{my_kpi_var}} ) %>%
    summarise( !!colName := {{my_fun}}({{my_var}}) ) %>%
    spread( key = {{my_kpi_var}}, colName ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    rename_at( vars(-{{my_org_var}}), str_c, "_", colName )
}
```

The column names are slightly different than your `df_numrtr` and `df_denom`, but this can be easily adjusted through additional string manipulation. I left it out to keep things clean.

```
fnSummarize( df, ORG_NM, KPI_NM, NUMR_VAL, mean )
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#    ORG_NM xxx_NUMR_VAL_mean yyy_NUMR_VAL_mean
#    <chr>              <dbl>             <dbl>
#  1 AAA                    9                 8
#  2 BBB                    1                 6
#  3 CCC                    9                 9
#  4 DDD                    1                NA

## Demonstrating using sum instead of mean
fnSummarize( df, ORG_NM, KPI_NM, DENO_VAL, sum )
#  # A tibble: 4 x 3
#    ORG_NM xxx_DENO_VAL_sum yyy_DENO_VAL_sum
#    <chr>             <dbl>            <dbl>
#  1 AAA                  20                3
#  2 BBB                   7                1
#  3 CCC                   3                4
#  4 DDD                   7               NA
```

---

I also want to point out that you can address your task through pure `dplyr` manipulations, without the need for `rlang`. For example, here's how you would apply both `sum` and `mean`:

```
df %>% group_by( ORG_NM, KPI_NM ) %>%
  summarize_at( c("NUMR_VAL", "DENO_VAL"), list(mean=mean,sum=sum) ) %>%
  ungroup() %>% gather( "Variable", "Value", -ORG_NM, -KPI_NM ) %>% 
  mutate( Variable = map2_chr(Variable, KPI_NM, ~str_replace(.x,"VAL",.y)) ) %>%
  select( -KPI_NM ) %>% spread( Variable, Value )
# # A tibble: 4 x 9
#    ORG_NM DENO_xxx_mean DENO_xxx_sum DENO_yyy_mean DENO_yyy_sum NUMR_xxx_mean
#    <chr>          <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
#  1 AAA               10           20             3            3             9
#  2 BBB                7            7             1            1             1
#  3 CCC                3            3             4            4             9
#  4 DDD                7            7            NA           NA             1
#  # … with 3 more variables: NUMR_xxx_sum <dbl>, NUMR_yyy_mean <dbl>,
#  #   NUMR_yyy_sum <dbl>
```

Comment: @Artem_Sokolov I am very grateful for your answer, will learn a lot from it. 

Regarding your last non function pure dplyr... If you wanted to turn it into function and pass the functions (mean, sum), how would you approach it? Pass the whole list(mean=mean,sum=sum) as argument or there is a more elegant way? Also I would like to pass c("NUMR_VAL", "DENO_VAL"). Should it be passed as the whole thing as argument? 

fnSummarize2( df, ORG_NM, KPI_NM, c("NUMR_VAL", "DENO_VAL"), list(mean=mean,sum=sum) ) .
Being unsure how to pass the list() thing I used three dots syntax "..."

Comment: @JacekKotowski: Yes, pretty much. For `summarize_at` to append the `_sum` and `_mean` suffix to each column, the function list needs to be named. Feeding `list(mean=mean, sum=sum)` is the most straightforward way, but with a bit of NSE magic, you can also infer the function names from `list(mean, sum)`.